# Macroprocessor in c++

Tags: c++

Hello everyone I am having doubt in this code

```
#include<iostream>
#define SQR(x)(x*x) 

int main() {
    int a, b=3;
    a = SQR(b+1);

    std::cout << a;
}
```

The result is 7 instead of 16 .I am not able to understand it .

Comment: The preprocessor is a *text-replacement* engine. It does no semantic parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro expands to a literal

```
(b + 1 * b + 1)
```

So your result is:

```
3 + (1 * 3) + 1.
```

Change your macro to:

```
#define SQR(x)((x)*(x))
```

And it should work.

Comment: I have a doubt when we write SQR(++x) and pass value of x as 3 then why would the result come out to be 25 in my case.

Comment: What you are seeing with SQR(++x) is [Undefined Behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/416627).

Comment: oh ok thanks but is there any way to do it correctly

Comment: Yes, do `++x; a = SQR(x);` Or, as james McLaughlin points out, don't use a macro.

Comment: Yeah, James McLaughlin has some really good alternatives.

Comment: In fact, change your MACRO to a function.

Answer (score 5):

After substituting the macro, the code looks like this:

```
int main() {
    int a, b=3;
    a = b+1*b+1;

    std::cout << a;
}
```

Which is the same as `b+(1*b)+1` with operator precedence.  You can fix it by either using a function instead:

```
inline int SQR(int x) {
    return x*x;
}
```

Or more generically:

```
template<class T> inline T SQR(T x) {
    return x*x;
}
```

Or by surrounding the macro parameters in parentheses:

```
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Which would expand to `((b+1)*(b+1))`.  In general I wouldn't recommend using a macro for this, however, because there are other potential problems, such as `SQR(x++)` expanding to `((x++)*(x++))`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code expands out to:

```
a = (b + 1 * b + 1)
```

Since `*` has more precedence than `+`, `1 * b` is evaluated first.