# C++ weird long long division (not common type conversion error)

Tags: c++

I was trying to do some newbie competitive programming problems (because currently i am a newbie :D).
I got this strange error with constant and long long division... And watched carefully about tipe conversion problems (can't see any).

I don't understand why such division, gives 1e18 instead of desired result...

```
#include <iostream>

#define ll long long
#define UPPER (ll)1e18 + 1

ll mult(ll first, ll second)
{
    ll div = UPPER / second;
    std::cout << UPPER / second << " " << UPPER << std::endl;
    if (first > div)
    {
        return UPPER;
    }

    return first * second;
}


int main()
{
    //51e10
    ll first = 510000000000, second = 510000000000;
    
    std::cout << mult(first, second);
}
```

And the output i get is:

```
1000000000000000000 1000000000000000001
908560695322214400
```

Comment: One more example of how stupid these "competitive programming" idiosyncraties are. Take a closer look at what your code looks like after `UPPER` has been substituted. Then ditch the insane macros, the [`std` namespace dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and the [needless compiler-specific header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: "duplicate" but in C: [The need for parentheses in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714). And never use `#define ll` to get long long. Use `int64_t` instead, or at least use `using` or `typedef` to redefine types

Comment: [Confused by squaring macro SQR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071504/995714), [Macroprocessor in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25873951/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are just simple text replacements. `UPPER / second` will be replaced with `(ll)1e18 + 1 / second` which is always equal to `(ll)1e18` unless second is 1

You must use parentheses around that

```
#define UPPER ((ll)1e18 + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! this solved my problem, the post can be closed now.

Comment: @Flecart you may accept an answer as having solved your issue and close your question by ticking the checkmark under the voting buttons on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using long long? I think this datatype refers to an integer right? I think you expect out of the divison a floating point number. I would suggest to try your approach with long double (which has the same size like long long). Type long double is a floating point type that is larger than or equal to type double.

Comment: no i don't i just needed a number under the first one. i needed to make a division for broader problem